# String as a JLabel name

Tags: java, string, swing

I am iterating through an ArrayList and for every value in it I want to create new JLabel. JLable name is supposed to be a value from my list.

```
ArrayList<String> fieldsList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int numberOfFields = 0; numberOfFields <= fieldsList.size(); numberOfFields++) {

        String fieldName = fieldsList.get(numberOfFields);

        JLabel "value from list"= new JLabel(fieldName + ":"); //here, in "" the name of JLabel should be the same as fieldName

    }
```

there is propably a simple solution to this, but i can't find it

Comment: you can not do it.. And what is use of it??

Comment: I always cringe when I see "get or assign variable name" in questions. Variable "names" aren't really all that important, don't exist for many objects, and *almost* don't exist in compiled code. And if an object is referred to by several variables, which one represents the "name" for this object?

Comment: Much more important are *object **references*** and how they can be obtained. If you must associate an object with a String, a clean way to do this is by using a Map such as a `HashMap<String, MyType>` or `HashMap<MyType, String>` depending on which you desire to use as the key, but again don't put too much reliance on variable names since non-final variables can change references at the drop of a hat, and objects can be referred to by more than one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
for (String fieldName : fieldsList) {
        {
            {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(fieldName + ":");
                lbl.setBounds(33, counter, 130, 14);
                getContentPane().add(lbl);
            }
            counter += 25;
        }
    }
```

it works for me

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it .alternative way is creating list of jlabel

```
ArrayList<String> fieldsList = new ArrayList<String>();

JLabel[] lablearr=new JLabel[fieldsList.size()]; //lable array

for (int numberOfFields = 0; numberOfFields < fieldsList.size(); numberOfFields++) {

        String fieldName = fieldsList.get(numberOfFields);

        lablearr[numberOfFields]= new JLabel(fieldName + ":"); 

 }
```

now if you want to call specific jlabel you can use

```
  lablearr[i]
```

for example if you want to call a jlable which name is `mylable:` then you loop through the arraylist - `fieldsList` and find the index of 'mylable' and call jlable by that index.